# Producer/consumer - Need to consume messages from python queue using threadpool

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, threadpool

I have created a Queue in python where i am inserting Kafka messages (which is coming continuously through Kafka topic).

In my main.py, an event loop is already running. I want to create a threadpool which will fetch the Kafka messages from the queue and process it. The threadpool should be running independently and should fetch the messages from queue whenever a new message arrives. How can i achieve this using async operation in Python.